# Not able to start broad leaf app with tomcat 8.5

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to deploy broad leaf app into tomcat 8.5.
I have created admin.war and deployed into tomcat 8.5 and started tomcat. In catalina.out, i have seen that admin.war deployed.

Logs are in catalina.out

```
13-Feb-2017 19:39:16.978 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/smusic-aio/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/webapps/admin.war has finished in 304 ms
serviceInfos:[TServiceInfo(serviceName:Catalina/localhost/admin and tomcat server started.
```

I tried to open admin page with http://localhost:8080/admin/, i got 404 error.
I am able to access http://localhost:8080.
Did i miss anything here? or do i need to change any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that you have both wars deployed to the same application context (`/`), were as we always deploy to `/` for the site war and `/admin` for the admin war.

[Checkout this screenshot for an example of how I setup the Admin war in IntelliJ.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QkNN.png)